# ASP.NET MVC onclick confirm if false redirects to an action even different one

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, redirect, onclick

I have a link in partial view, which is an easy list of items which I can open to edit/delete.

The link to delete has confirm
 - when I press OK, everything is fine
 - when I press cancel, it redirects it anyway but not even to the Delete controller's action but to the Detail.

**EDIT**
this one redirects to the DETAIL always => doesnt delete anything

```
<a href="#" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this item?')) location.href = '@Url.Action("Delete", "Items", new { id = item.ItemID })'; return false;">Delete</a>
```

this one redirects to detail only if pressed cancel => deletes when OK, doesnt work on cancel

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Items", new { id = item.ItemID }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure to delete this item?')" })
```

I have tried it without the return false, putting to onclick return confirm(..), but nothing seems to work and if I press cancel I end up redirected to /Items/Detail/ID, which I completely dont understand and the delete method in the controller is not called.

controller - detail that is being called if I press cancel

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Detail(int id)
    {
        TravelRequest model = DB.TravelRequests.Where(m => m.TravelRequestID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        ViewBag.AttachmentFilePath = model.AttachmentFilePath;

        SetDetailCommons(model);
        return View("Create", model);
    }
```

Delete which does not happen (which is OK because it shoult not be called if I press cancel...)

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        var model = DB.TravelRequests.Where(m => m.TravelRequestID == id).First();
        DB.TravelRequests.Remove(DB.TravelRequests.Where(m => m.TravelRequestID == id).First());
        DB.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Detail", "Assignment", new { id = model.AssignmentID });
    }
```

Thank you for any suggestions :)

Comment: try using ActionName like  [HttpGet, ActionName("Delete")] and best practice change the name of the ActionResult from "Delete" to something else

Comment: Well when I click OK, then it deletes the correct item. But, when I press cancel, instead of doing nothing and staying on the page it gets redirected to the Detail page, which is wrong. I will edit the Q to make it clearer :)

Comment: Do you have a click handler on an ancestor of the delete button that takes you to the detail? I would guess the event is propagating to that handler (even though the return false should prevent that).

Comment: there is a form starting after the list
    
    {
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create form</h2>

@if (Model != null && Model.ParentModelID != 0)
{
    @Html.Partial("ItemssIndex", Model.Itemss.OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedDate))
}
     using (Html.BeginForm())
{

Comment: ok, I found what you were talking about... it is in a table row which has onclick...  
so now it works without the table row onclick, but, what if I want to keep both options ?  
<tr onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Detail", "Itemss", new { id = item.ItemID } )'" class="link-row">

Comment: Honestly, I would lose the inline event handlers and bind them from javascript. That would give you the ability to use `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` reliably, and is just generally cleaner.

Comment: OK, will try that :) thanks, can you put your first answer as an answer so i can set it the right one ? cheers